# How to correctly link JMockIt in a new runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jmockit

I'm using Jmockit 1.30 in my Java Project with Eclipse.
I've added `jmockit.jar` as an external jar to my project, and now I need to pack all my project in a runnable .jar file. So I went to "export.." -> "Runnable Jar" and then selected "package required libraries into generated jar". 
But when I try to execute the jar with `java -jar myjar.jar` I get weird exceptions referencing Jmockit library that I don't know how to handle.

Instead, if I start java with `java -cp .:../lib/jmockit.jar com.mypackage.client.Main` everything works fine. Any ideas on how to solve it and why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

> But when I try to execute the jar with java -jar myjar.jar I get weird exceptions referencing Jmockit library

You have Test code mixed in your production code.

Best way to avoid that is to omit eclipses standard project directory layout and switch to the [`maven` standard layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).
This has separate folders for production code and test code so that it is easy to create the jar for shipment without the test code.